# Assembly Clarification

Tags: assembly, x86

Working on an object dumped executable. Just want to clarify what is happening in a couple lines.

```
 movl   $0x8049594,-0x8(%ebp) 
# ? This stores the value of 0x8049594 in the memory location of %ebp - 8?

 mov    -0x8(%ebp),%esi 
#? Does this just take that value at %ebp-8 and put it in %esi, making %esi's val 0x8049594?

mov    (%esi),%edi # sets %edi to value stored in %esi
```

Thanks in advance. Hope this is sufficient enough to understand what's going on in these particular lines.

Comment: First two, yes. Last one is loading `edi` from memory pointed to by `esi`.

Comment: Thanks Jester! I appreciate the quick help